# Product pages load at the bottom of the screen

Tags: products-view

My product view is suddenly loading at the bottom of the page requiring visitors to scroll up. This is affecting all of my products.

What code I can use to force the page to the top upon load so that visitors are not required to scroll up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

most likely you have a form in the footer that is set on autofocus.
This happens when you created a from js object like this:

```
var someForm = new VarienForm('some-id', true);
```

the second parameter means `firstFieldFocus`. So if you set it to true then the first field in the form will be autofocused when loading the page.
There is no need for js workarounds. Just make the second param `false`;

<sub>My money is on a newsletter form</sub>

Comment: You were right on the money! I had a custom contact form in easy tabs. Implemented your suggestion and removed the java script and it worked. Thanks Marius!

Comment: Ive been pulling my hair out with this! Marius you really are the man!

Comment: @Marius Where do I find this code? I am still having this problem and it is serious (many customers don't know what to do when they get to the Payment option screen because the screen loads at the bottom and they don't see the actual payment options)

Comment: @Allysin It should be in the newsletter template file.

Comment: @Marius Do you mean what's under System - Configuration - Customers - Newsletter - under Success Email Template, Unsubscription Email Template, Confirmation Email Template that I should be able to edit under System - transactional Emails - Add a new Template? When I click on the Add a new Template - I don't get any drop down options under Load default template - template*  I'm on Magento 1.9.1. I'm looking for any solution to fix this even if it's not the most elegant one...

Comment: @Marius I found a bunch of files in /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model including Template.php - is that it?

Comment: enable template path hints and you should see a phtml file name

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was simply going to `opcheckout_rwd.js` and added this code

Find this section:

```
this.currentStep = section;
    var sectionElement = $('opc-' + section);
    sectionElement.addClassName('allow');
    this.accordion.openSection('opc-' + section);
```

Added this line:

```
$j('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $j('#checkoutSteps').offset().top}, 15);
```

Scroll viewport to top of checkout steps for smaller viewports

```
if (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: ' + bp.xsmall + 'px)')) {
    $j('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $j('#checkoutSteps').offset().top}, 800);
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it did not help. I have the Porto theme - is that why? How could I do the same with the Porto theme? My customers are abandoning the cart when they get to the Payment steps because it's bringing them all the way to the bottom of the page and they do not see the actual Payment options...

Answer (score -1):

This can be resolved with java script. You need to add the following code at the bottom of view.phtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload= function(){
parent.window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
</script>
```

This will automatically scroll the visitors window to the top of the page.

Comment: which view.phtml are you talking about? I have this problem when customers click on CONTINUE on step 3 (SHIPPING METHOD) it loads the BOTTOM of step 4 (PAYMENT INFORMATION) - you cannot see the payment options at all! You have to scroll up to see them! This is a real problem because many customers are not able to figure out they have to scroll up...How can I correct this?

Comment: I am willing to do anything at this moment to get rid of this problem (customers abandon sales because they do not see the Payment options because the screen scrolls all the way to the bottom). I found a few of the view.phtml files = in "\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\review" and also in "app\design\frontend\base\default\template\review\customer" and "app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\sales\recurring\profile" Where should I add this code to? Thank you so much!

Comment: I've put this into view.phtml in 5 different places but it still doesn't work: 1. app\design\frontend\base\default\template\review 2. app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\review 3. app\design\frontend\base\default\template\review\customer 4. app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\sales\recurring\profile and 5. app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\sales\billing\agreement